# c3p0 doesn't acquire a connection, but there are idle connections

Tags: hibernate, c3p0

My JAVA application processes a number of requests at a time using multithreading. So, different requests are processed at the same time with different threads.

I'm accessing my Oracle database with hibernate and C3P0, using the following hibernate.properties:

```
hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer=false
hibernate.connection.driver_class=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
hibernate.search.autoregister_listeners=false

hibernate.connection.url=${jdbc.url}
hibernate.default_schema=${jdbc.schema}
hibernate.connection.username=${jdbc.username}
hibernate.connection.password=${jdbc.password}

hibernate.c3p0.min_size=5
hibernate.c3p0.max_size=10
hibernate.c3p0.timeout=1800
hibernate.c3p0.max_statements=50
```

And c3p0.properties:

```
c3p0.preferredTestQuery=SELECT 1 from dual
c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckin=true
c3p0.idleConnectionTestPeriod=10
c3p0.driverClass=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
```

(I've also tested it with testConnectionOnCheckout instead of testConnectionOnCheckin).

My java code does the following:

```
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    try{                
        session.beginTransaction();

        Log.debug(localizator + "Start");
        processCounters(id, user, session);
        Log.debug(localizator + "Stop");
        session.getTransaction().commit();

    } finally{
        session.close();
    }
```

When I run this it prints "Start" for every thread, but gets "locked" in one persist to the database, and no "Stop" is printed.

If I watch the opened sessions at database, there're 10 opened sessions (the max number configured at c3p0), but all of them are idle.
Is there a way to make c3p0 releases some idle connections so, at least, one of the thread ends its process (appart from increasing the number of max connections)?

Comment: You probably have bigger problems that that - I suspect your `processCounters` method is creating a deadlock. Maybe take a thread dump and look through it.

Comment: Don't think so. It ends when the seconds at timeout passes, so it was an issue with the idle connections that weren't released. I've changed c3p0 for BoneCP and now it works like a charm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the connection pool to BoneCP has solved the issue. I've used the following configuration (which I think it could be tuned to improve even more the speed of the process):

```
bonecp.idleMaxAge=240
bonecp.idleConnectionTestPeriod=60
bonecp.partitionCount=3
bonecp.acquireIncrement=1
bonecp.maxConnectionsPerPartition=5
bonecp.minConnectionsPerPartition=2
bonecp.statementsCacheSize=50
bonecp.releaseHelperThreads=3
```

Now it doesn't hang and, what is better, it has increased the performance of the queries.